# ehcache - GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, ehcache

We are having an issue with caching gson object using ehcache. The gson objects count start to raise and when the GC is executed, nothing happens. The objects count continue until GC overhead limit exceeded.

***Code1:***

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search2")
    @Cacheable(value = "halfHourCache", keyGenerator = "haodfKeyGenerator")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object search2(BizData bizData, Page page, String sourceType)  {
        return SearchSourceRunner.search(bizData, page, sourceType, DiseaseKeyWorldFilter.class);
    }
```

This is JVM heap monitor:

[image]

But if we cache String instead of gson object, the heap is fine. The cached String objects can be clear by the GC.

***Code2***

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search")
    @Cacheable(value = "halfHourCache", keyGenerator = "haodfKeyGenerator")
    public ResponseEntity<String> search(BizData bizData, Page page, String sourceType)  {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Gson().toJson(SearchSourceRunner.search(bizData, page, sourceType, DiseaseKeyWorldFilter.class)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

***Question:***

What's the difference between Code1 and Code2?  Why Code2 can work fine, but Code1 get an exception of GC overhead limit exceeded?

Comment: I'd advice you to take heap dump and analyze it. It is difficult to say more without it.